# Mykrobe predictor JSON to TSV Converter

Tags: python, json, linux, bioinformatics

I wanted to ask a question regarding file conversion.

I have a JSON file (after AMR prediction execution) that I want to covert to a TSV file based on Mykrobe-predictor scripts (json_to_tsv.py) and this is my JSON output ([result_TB.json](http://bioinfo.cs.ccu.edu.tw/result_TB.json)).

```
./json_to_tsv.py /path/to/JSON_file
```

When I pasted a command into the terminal, I got a IndexError at Line 78.

https://github.com/iqbal-lab/Mykrobe-predictor/blob/master/scripts/json_to_tsv.py#L78

```
 def get_sample_name(f):
  return f.split('/')[-2]
```

And here is the error I get:

```
mykrobe_version file plate_name sample drug phylo_group species lineage phylo_group_per_covg species_per_covg lineage_per_covg phylo_group_depth species_depth lineage_depth susceptibility variants (gene:alt_depth:wt_depth:conf) genes (prot_mut-ref_mut:percent_covg:depth)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./json_to_tsv.py", line 157, in <module>
  sample_name = get_sample_name(f)
  File "./json_to_tsv.py", line 78, in get_sample_name
  return f.split('/')[-2]
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the JSON output to the question?

Comment: Sure, no prob.
I have attached my JSON outcome (result_TB.json) for your consideration.
Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code I guess they expect to call the converter with something like:

```
python json_to_tsv.py plate/sample1/sample1.json
```

Try copying your JSON file to a directory called `sample1` inside a directory called `plate` and see if you get the same error when you call it like in the example above.

---

**Update**

The problem is indeed as described above.

**Doesn't work:**

```
python json_to_tsv.py result_TB.json
```

> mykrobe_version   file    plate_name  sample  drug    phylo_group species lineage phylo_group_per_covg    species_per_covg    lineage_per_covg    phylo_group_depth   species_depth   lineage_depth   susceptibility  variants
>   (gene:alt_depth:wt_depth:conf)    genes
>   (prot_mut-ref_mut:percent_covg:depth)
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "json_to_tsv.py", line 157, in <module>
>     sample_name = get_sample_name(f)   File "json_to_tsv.py", line 78, in get_sample_name
>     return f.split('/')[-2] IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

**Works:**

```
python json_to_tsv.py plate/sample/result_TB.json
```

> mykrobe_version   file    plate_name  sample  drug    phylo_group species lineage phylo_group_per_covg    species_per_covg    lineage_per_covg    phylo_group_depth   species_depth   lineage_depth   susceptibility  variants (gene:alt_depth:wt_depth:conf) genes (prot_mut-ref_mut:percent_covg:depth)
>
> -1    result_TB   plate   sample  NA

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the absolute path in the positional arguments, and got the same result (1 result_TB yiting104 Mykrobe NA).

`./json_to_tsv.py /bip6_disk/yiting104/Mykrobe/result_TB.json > result_TB.tsv`